# Bitcoin-core download more then blockchain size

Tags: bitcoind

I have installed bitcoin-core on my digitalocean droplet and configured with the following bitcoin.conf:

```
datadir=/mnt/volume_name/Bitcoin
dbcache=1000
txindex=1
server=1
rpcuser=rpcuser
rpcpassword=rpcpassword
rpcport=8332
```

Then I start daemon, it begin to synchronize. Volume size is 500Gb, I thought it will be enough space for bitcoin blockchain, which for now is [around 414 Gb](https://ycharts.com/indicators/bitcoin_blockchain_size). But, after a few days I realized that the volume is full!

```
$ df -h

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
--- // ---
/dev/sda        496G  471G  4.0K 100% /mnt/volume_name
--- // ---
```

At the moment it stopped working and obviously it can't start again. Why does it continue to fill all space on the disk? I know it has to be some misconfiguration, but I don't understand what exactly is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to "define the size of a blockchain".

Bitcoind likely needs multiple database indexes that multiply the space needed on the disk, as storing the raw blocks it not enough for a functional bitcoind setup.